# DIsplaying all methods definitions

Tags: phpstorm

is there a way to find all functions definitions by a word in all the libraries using PHPStorm ? For example : I type "get" and i would like the search to return all the methods that contains "get" from all the classes ( EX : NameContext, Session, DriverInterface etc.).

Or, is there a way to set autocomplete return results from all project classes and not only the class you`re working with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use navigate to symbol to find methods by name.

Go to Navigate -> Symbol or press Ctrl+Shift+Alt+N to open the dialog. Then simply enter (part of) the name, and PhpStorm will display all matches.

You can also simply use find in path (Edit -> Find -> Find in Path) to search everywhere for "function somename", which should usually work just as well.

More information:

- https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/navigating-to-class-file-or-symbol-by-name.html
- https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/find-and-replace-in-path.html